# Stopping setTimeout loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have this function to create an animation of dropping box:

```
function dropBox(y, width, height) {
    var img_box = new Image();
    img_box.src = 'images/gift_box_small.png';

    var box_y_pos = y;
    if(y==0)
        box_y_pos = y-img_box.naturalHeight;


    img_box.onload = function(){
        ctx_overlay.save();
        ctx_overlay.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
        ctx_overlay.drawImage(img_box, (width/2)-(img_box.naturalWidth/2), box_y_pos);
        ctx_overlay.restore();
    }

    box_y_pos += 3;

    var loopTimer = setTimeout(function() {dropBox(box_y_pos, width, height)},24);
}
```

I want to stop the animation when the box reaches a certain Y position and call for other function. I can't have a code to check for Y position before the setTimeout declaration, since it hasn't been declared yet, and I can't have it after, since it'll be unreachable. So how can it be done?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Just wrap the the `setTimeout` call inside a condition? e.g. `if(y < something) { setTimeout... }`

Comment: @Alexandros here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n2derqgw/

Comment: @Yoshi Your suggestion worked just fine for me, thank you! Could you please post it as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply pass pass extra variable of the stop_y position to your function. And call setTimeout() only if box did not reach yet this position:

```
function dropBox(y, width, height, stop_y) {
        var img_box = new Image();
        img_box.src = 'http://corkeynet.com/test/images/gift_box_small.png';

        var box_y_pos = y;
        if(y==0)
            box_y_pos = y-img_box.naturalHeight;


        img_box.onload = function(){
            ctx_overlay.save();
            ctx_overlay.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
            ctx_overlay.drawImage(img_box, (width/2)-(img_box.naturalWidth/2), box_y_pos);
            ctx_overlay.restore();
        }

        box_y_pos += 3;
        if (box_y_pos < stop_y) {
            var loopTimer = setTimeout(function() {dropBox(box_y_pos, width, height, stop_y)},24);
        }
    }
```

Edited your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/93jwqf2j/